# Project import giving Google Play Service error

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am working on Open Data Kit. I have cloned the ODK Collect repo on my system.

Now whenever i try to import the Android Project in my Android Studio,
i get the following error

```
* Project ODK Collect:D:\Development\opendatakit.collect\project.properties:
Library reference ..\playservices could not be found
Path is D:\Development\opendatakit.collect\..\playservices which resolves to D:\Development\playservices
```

I have put the Google-Play-Services JAR file in the project folder.
Please guide with detailed steps.

**I SEARCHED FOR SIMILAR QUESTIONS, AND NONE OF THE SOLUTIONS WORK**

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `Unrecoverable error`

[image]

**First open eclipse and open project remove all errors make project runnable.**

If you don't have ecclipse installed then delete (keep backup) `project.properties` file from the project

Now try to import your project in **Android Studio** you will not get `Unrecoverable error`

Now to add dependency

1. Right click on the project folder click **Open Module Setting**
2. Goto **dependency** tab (last one)
3. Select **+** button on the right side , Select **Library dependency**.
4. Scroll to Google play service and select it.

Now you will be able to `import` and work with `Google play service.`

Comment: I cannot start the Android Studio. When i click on Import Eclipse ADt Project and select this one, then the error pops up. It says it is an unrecoverable error.

Comment: I updated my answer now you will not get unrecoverable error. I also mentioned why this error is occurring.

Comment: Okay. Will have to install Eclipse and ADT now. :/ Isnt there a better way?

Comment: If you don't have ecclipse installed then delete (keep backup) project.properties file from the project, And follow step from the top of my answer.

Comment: Now try to import your project in Android Studio.